# Selecting a specific Azure Location using Get-AzLocation

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to find a way to select a targeted Azure Location (object) using Azure PowerShell.

This gives me the list of locations:

```
Get-AzLocation | select DisplayName, Location | Format-Table
```

How do I select 1 of them, something like...

```
$Location = Get-AzLocation -Something "South Central US"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1) to filter on `DisplayName`:

```
❯ Get-AzLocation | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "South Central US"}

Location    : southcentralus
DisplayName : South Central US
Providers   : {Microsoft.Automation, Microsoft.Storage, Microsoft.Network, Microsoft.Compute…}
```

Which will return you an object of type [`Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceProviderLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.resourcemanager.cmdlets.sdkmodels.psresourceproviderlocation?view=azurerm-ps).